# How do I make command blocks teleport players away from an area when they don't have a specific item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make command blocks that teleports players away from an area, like 2 blocks or so, repeatedly, when they don't have a specific item? I'm trying to make an adventure map that would require certain items to proceed to the next portion of the map.

I want the command blocks to search players inventory for a diamond. If they have a diamond nothing happens. If they do not have diamond it teleports the player backwards 2 blocks. The issue is the first block is a repeating block that searches the players inventory within 2 block range. The second block is a chain block for testforblock (repeating block) successcount:0.  Third block tp's ~ ~ ~2. I want the teleport to happen once unless the player reenters the radius. As it is, it teleports infinitely backwards and I have to disable command blocks to fix it.

Comment: You added the "`minecraft-feed-the-beast`" tag. Does that mean you're playing with mods? Then you should say that in the question.

Comment: Can it happen that multiple players are in the area and some have the item, some not, so that only the ones without the item should get teleported?

Comment: Would it be acceptable for you to update your Minecraft version to one of the latest snapshots? That would make it much easier, but of course they are unstable and buggy, so you might not want to run an important world in it.

Comment: @Fabian if the tag indicates the mod, then there is no need to also say so in the body. With that said, there are an awful lot of unnecessary tags here =)

Comment: "minecraft" was actually useful, because it indicated the Java Edition.

Comment: Its not on FTB at all but it is on minecraft that should still be there

Comment: only the players with the item should not be teleported. I only want the players teleported a few blocks back from the area they try to access. Players that have said item should be able to walk past untouched

Comment: To be more specific:I want the command blocks to search players inventory for a diamond. if they have diamond nothing happens. If they do not have diamond it teleports the player backwards 2 blocks. The issue is the first block is a repeating block that searches the players inventory within 2block range. the second block is a chain block for testforblock (repeating block) successcount:0 third block tp's ~ ~ ~2. I want the teleport to happen once unless the player reenters the radius. As is it, it teleports infinitly backwards and i have to disable command blocks to fix it.

Comment: That is because you're using testfor (which is bad practice, because it has some obvious flaws). Try tagging players that enter the area that have the item with a scoreboard tag and then teleport those in the area without the tag back.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to use [scoreboard tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags).  This will allow you to tag any player that has diamond and use that tag to [target them](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) within the tp command.

---

Use 3 command blocks in a chain. The first command block removes the tag from all players.   The second command block tags any players who have a diamond in their inventory.  The third command block teleports any player within the [boundaries](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_coordinate) of the target selector who do not have the tag.

These command blocks have to remain loaded.  I recommend putting them in the [spawn chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk).  I also recommend stopping command block output to prevent chat spam for op players. Use command:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

The first command block is <kbd>Repeat</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a remove Obtained
```

The second command block is <kbd>Chain</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add Obtained {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]}
```

The Third command block is <kbd>Chain</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
tp @a[x=X,y=Y,z=Z,r=R,tag=!Obtained] ~ ~ ~2
```

Replace X, Y, and Z with the coordinates of your gate area.  Replace R with the desired radius for that area.

Comment: Thank you for this information its been super helpful!!!

Comment: Glad I could help.  If the answer solved your problem, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  This lets future visitors with the same problem know that it solved your problem.  If it did not solve your problem, I recommend editing your question with the extra details in order to get the exact solution you are looking for.